# Limit results to the first 2 ranking rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, window-functions, rank

In SQL Server 2008, I am using `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Col2 ORDER BY Col3 DESC)` to return data set with `RANK`. But I have hundreds of records for each partition, so I will get values from rank 1, 2, 3......999. But I want only up to 2 `RANKs` in each `PARTITION`.

Example:

```
ID   Name    Score    Subject
1    Joe      100      Math
2    Jim      99       Math
3    Tim      98       Math
4    Joe      99       History
5    Jim      100      History
6    Tim      89       History
7    Joe      80       Geography
8    Tim      100      Geography
9    Jim      99       Geography
```

I want the result to be:

```
SELECT Subject, Name, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Subject ORDER BY Score DESC)
FROM Table
```

```
Subject        Name      Rank
Math           Joe        1
Math           Jim        2
History        Jim        1
History        Joe        2
Geography      Tim        1
Geography      Jim        2
```

I want only rank 1 and 2 in each category. How do I do this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You could put the original query using `rank()` into a subquery and wrap it with a query that filters the results.

Comment: Makes sense. I wish Microsoft would make it more simple i.e. put a number in the RANK function. `RANK(2) OVER (PARTITION BY Col2 ORDER B Y Col3) AS Top_2_Ranks`. May be it will happen in future releases. Thanks for the idea though.

Comment: @UB01: Or better yet, it would be nice to use windowed functions in a `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 19):

```
select * from (
SELECT Subject, Name, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Subject ORDER BY Score DESC) as RN
FROM Table
) a
where a.RN <= 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to do this in SQL Server is to combine the window function with a common table expression:

```
with cte as (
SELECT Subject, Name, RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Subject ORDER BY Score DESC) as ordinal
FROM Table
)
select * from cte where ordinal <= 2
```

Answer (score -1):

For Teradara alternatively you can do:

```
SELECT 
Subject, 
Name, 
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Subject ORDER BY Score DESC) as RN
FROM Table
QUALIFY a.RN <= 2
```

Comment: Well, that might be all right, but the question is specifically about SQL Server.